# How to reproduce this plot of an exponential?

Tags: plotting

How do I reproduce the gist of the following plot in Mathematica?

[image]

Comment: No code, no data, nothing? Don't you think you could make a bit more of an effort here? You posted two questions (the other being [211049](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/211049/27951)) that essentially just ask for people to do your work for you in the last hour...

Comment: MarcoB: I answered the question below. Not my intention to abuse mathematica.stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

The following gets close enough:

```
Plot[{E^(x/5), Log[x] + 0.8}, {x, 1, 10}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotLabel -> "GPU Moore's Law", 
 FrameLabel -> {"Time", "Computing Power"}, 
 FrameTicks -> {None, None}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"GPU Moore's Law (Alive)", 
   "CPU Moore's Law (Dead)"}, ImageSize -> 700, 
 PlotTheme -> "Marketing"]
```

though using `Log` for CPU Moore's Law isn't perfect (it would be nice to show it going from exponential to something more logarithmic).

[image]